# Data-Types that are more suitable for recursion than others?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a Homework to find Data-Types that are suitable for Recursive Methods, but i can't seem to find something on that.

Comment: What does your textbook say in the chapter on Recursion?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too vague. Are you talking about recursive data structures, or are you talking about data types suitable for a recursive method? Can you elaborate on what the question really is about?

Comment: There are plenty of recursive algorithms working on arrays, lists, trees, stacks, heaps, graphs etc. You should just find few examples on such common algorithms and learn what data structures they use.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen data types suitable for revursive methods

Answer (score 0):

are you are talking about data structures that are composed of the same or similar data structure?

Like trees can have references to other trees (sub trees) and lists can have nodes that have references to another nodes.

https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/recursivstrc.html

Comment: Consider editing your answer and adding some code so if that link goes dead, the answer is still useful